# Three digit number even and greater than $500$

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, probability-theory, permutations, recreational-mathematics

I am reading the following problem:

> The digits $1$,$2$,$3$,$4$,$5$ are randomly arranged to form a three
> digit number (digits are not repeated). What is the probability that
> the number is even and greater than $500$?

My solution:
There are $5\cdot 4 \cdot 3$ ways to form the number in total.
In order to be greater than $500$ the first digit must be $5$ and in order to be even the last digit must be either $2$ or $4$. So there is $1$ way to select the first digit, $2$ ways to select the last and $2$ ways to select the middle one (either $3$ or $4$) i.e. $2\cdot 2\cdot 1$ = $4$ ways
Therefore the probability is: $\frac{4}{60}=\frac{1}{15}$

But the solution mentions $\frac{1}{10}$.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do you think there are $2$ choices for the middle digit again?  What about numbers like $524$?

Comment: For each choice of the first and last digit you have three choices for the middle digit, not just two.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Ah I see. But how can I express that without repetition? I.e. for the last digit I can have either $2$ or $4$.

Comment: @primes.against.humanity: How can I express that though without repetition? For the first position it is only $1$ option namely $5$. For the last it has to be either $2$ or $4$. If I pick $3$ for the middle I would have repetitions right?

Comment: Yes... you don't have to specifically *name* the options ahead of time, you just have to specify a manner in which given earlier choices you *could name* the options.  This is just like how when counting the number of permutations of the numbers $1,2,3,4,5$ you have $5$ options for the first number *and given whatever that first number happened to be* you have the four remaining options to choose from for the next, etc... which yields the calculation $5\times 4\times 3\times 2\times 1$, simplified as $5!$.

Comment: Here, we pick the first digit to be $5$... there is one option.  We then pick the last digit and have two options, $2$ and $4$.  Now... let's call what we picked for that last digit $\ell$.  For the middle digit we have the options $\{1,2,3,4\}\color{red}{\setminus \{\ell\}}$, whatever $\ell$ happened to be and thus have $3$ choices *given the earlier choice for $\ell$*.

Comment: @JMoravitz: But if ℓ is e.g. $2$ and also $2$ is part of that small set, doesn't it imply it could repeat?

Comment: No.  If $\ell$ is two then the small set is $\{1,3,4\}$.  Meanwhile, if $\ell$ is four then the small set is $\{1,2,3\}$.  The small set can change depending on what $\ell$ is.  That is the point.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Does that notation you used with the `\\` signify that the ℓ is different from the previous choice?

Comment: The notation I used was [set difference](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SetDifference.html).  $A\setminus B = \{x~:~x\in A~\text{and}~x\notin B\}$

Comment: I guess https://www.slader.com/discussion/question/the-digits-1-2-3-4-and-5-are-randomly-arranged-to-form-a-three-digit-number-digits-are-not-repeated/ might help you

Answer (score 2):

J Moravitz' comment addresses the flaw.

The easiest alternative approach is that there are $D = 5!$ numbers possible, of which $4!$ of the numbers start with the digit $5.$  By symmetry, there are $N = \frac{4!}{2}$ such numbers that are even.  So the desired probability is $\frac{N}{D}.$

**Addendum**
Per OP's request, I will combine his analysis with the analysis inherent in the comments of J Moravitz to provide an alternative **direct** approach to the problem.

As in the start of my answer, the computation will be

$$\frac{N}{D}, ~~\text{where}~~ D = 5!.$$

The leftmost digit must be $5$.  The rightmost digit must be either $2$ or $4$. I will let $N_1$ denote the number of possibilities where the rightmost digit is $2$.  Then, by symmetry, $N = 2 \times N_1$.

With the leftmost and rightmost digits being $5$ and $2$ respectively, the other 3 digits, $1,3,4$ can be permuted in $3!$ ways to fill in the 3 middle digits.

Therefore, $N_1 = 3!$ and $N = 2 \times 3!$.

Comment: What do you mean "by symmetry"?

Comment: You are arranging the numbers $1,2,3,4$. Half of those are even ($2,4$) and half are odd ($1,3$), so across all arrangements, there will an equal number of even and odd arrangements. We call this symmetry because each unique even number you generate can be used to generate a unique odd number, and vice-versa (for example $512$ and $521$; or $543$ and $534$), so all the results come in symmetric pairs

Comment: @RhysHughes Thanks, beat me to it.

Comment: @user2661923: very smart solution. May I suggest you include JMoravitz points, and I will accept the answer

Comment: It just hit me: are you suggesting that I edit my answer to include a second approach that uses J Moravitz' analysis?  If so, no problem.  Let me know if this is what you are thinking.

Comment: @user2661923: Yes, sometimes for me, when I read posts, it is easier to read the anwers than the comments or at least for me the answers take my attention more. Hence it might be more helpful to include everything. So yes to your second question. But that may be just me, if it not the protocol here, I can accept it as is, no problem

Comment: @Jim answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

The total space of events consists of $ 5*4*3 = 60  $  3-digit numbers, consisting of non-repeating digits $ 1, 2, 3, 4$ and $5 $.

Of them, only those that start with $5$ and end with $2$ or $4$ are even greater than $500$.

If the last digit is "$2$", then the second digit is any of $1, 3,$ and$ 4$  ($3$ possibilities).

If the last digit is "$4$", then the second digit is any of $1, 3,$ and $2$  ($3$ possibilities).

In all, there are $3+3 = 6$  of these "eligible" numbers.

So the probability will  be $ \frac{6}{60} $